# SQL totals dynamic pivot

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

I have a dynamic pivot with a total at the bottom of each column however I am trying to add a total at the end of each row.

My SQL is below

```
SELECT @Cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' +QUOTENAME(PRD_ValidDate)
            FROM #Table
            GROUP BY PRD_ValidDate
            ORDER BY PRD_ValidDate
        FOR XML PATH (''), Type).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SELECT @ColsWithNoNulls = STUFF((SELECT  distinct ',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(PRD_ValidDate) + ', 0) ' + QUOTENAME(PRD_ValidDate)
            FROM #Table
            GROUP BY PRD_ValidDate
        FOR XML PATH (''), Type).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @Query = 
'
SELECT cardtype as [Card Type],' + @ColsWithNoNulls + '  FROM
(
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(Cardtype AS VARCHAR(30)),''TOTAL'') CardType, ISNULL(SUM    (AllEntries),0) as AllEntries, PRD_ValidDate FROM #Table
GROUP BY cardtype,  prd_Validdate
WITH CUBE
 ) src
PIVOT
( SUM(AllEntries)
 For PRD_ValidDate IN ('+@Cols+')) piv
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN (CardType=''TOTAL'')THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CardType'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to create a UNION that does the summing at the end of your query.  I've given you an example below.  I'm not sure I've given you all the correct syntax not knowing your tables. Also, dates can't be totaled, so I assumed you wanted the number of days, so I used a function to total the number of days.

```
        SELECT cardtype as [Card Type],' + @ColsWithNoNulls + '  FROM
        (SELECT ISNULL(CAST(Cardtype AS VARCHAR(30)),''TOTAL'') CardType, 
         ISNULL(SUM    (AllEntries),0) as AllEntries, PRD_ValidDate FROM #Table
        GROUP BY cardtype,  prd_Validdate
        WITH CUBE) src
        PIVOT
        ( SUM(AllEntries)
         For PRD_ValidDate IN ('+@Cols+')) piv
         UNION 
         select sum((SELECT ISNULL(CAST(Cardtype AS VARCHAR(30)),''TOTAL'')), 
 sum(ISNULL(SUM (AllEntries),0)) as AllEntries, days(PRD_ValidDate) FROM 
    SELECT cardtype as [Card Type],' + @ColsWithNoNulls + '  FROM
    (SELECT ISNULL(CAST(Cardtype AS VARCHAR(30)),''TOTAL'') CardType, 
     ISNULL(SUM    (AllEntries),0) as AllEntries, PRD_ValidDate FROM #Table
    GROUP BY cardtype,  prd_Validdate
    WITH CUBE) src
    PIVOT
    ( SUM(AllEntries)
     For PRD_ValidDate IN ('+@Cols+')) piv
```

Comment: Thanks Karlomanio, the pivot is counting 'AllEntries' split by date (along the top) and card type down the left side), so the total would be summing the Allentries of card type, as I already have the sum of all entries by date. I added the code you attached however I get the below syntax errors 

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
and
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: If you could mark the answer as correct.  I changed the statement a bit.  Somehow the SQL statement got messed up. Thanks.